# Sustituir valores de una llave en JSON

Tags: json, angular, backend, schedule

Estoy implementando en Angular el Scheduler de https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/schedule/remote-data, obtendo mis datos desde mi backend en Codeigniter en este formato:

```
[{
"Id": 1,
"Subject": "Blue Moon Eclipse",
"StartTime": "2020-09-28 19:34:14",
"EndTime": "2020-09-29 00:00:00",

}]
```

y debo formatearlo asi:

```
   [
       {
            Id: 1,
            Subject: 'Blue Moon Eclipse',
            StartTime: new Date(2020, 9, 28, 19, 34),
            EndTime: new Date(2020, 09, 29, 0, 0),
        }
    ]
```

He buscado varias soluciones pero no logrohacer que funciones. este fue lo ultimo que probé pero algo estoy haciendo muy mal

```
this.pacientesService.getConsultas(doctor_id).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.consultas=data

      let regexAMPM = /\"([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\-([0-9][0-9])\-([0-9][0-9])\s([0-9][0-9])\:([0-9][0-9])\:([0-9][0-9])\"/;

      Object.keys(this.consultas).map(  //recorrer todo el objeto
        clave => {
          data[clave] = data[clave].replace(
            regexAMPM,
            (match, grupo1) => grupo1 == new Date(\1,\2,\3,\4,\5)
          );
        });

      console.log(this.consultas);
```

Answer (score 0):

El valor que te manda desde el backend es un string facilmente parseable a un Date, y eso es lo que haces con esto `StartTime: new Date(2020, 9, 28, 19, 34),`.
En este caso únicamente tienes que parsear en tu respuesta.

```
this.pacientesService.getConsultas(doctor_id).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.consultas = data;
  //Si genera error de tipos, aplicalo a data.
  this.consultas.forEach( (e) => {
    e.StartTime =  new Date(e.StartTime);
    e.EndTime =  new Date(e.EndTime),
  });
});
```

Ahora si te inquieta que el formato pueda no parsear por la configuración local de la maquina, lo que te recomiendo es que uses la librería [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Parseas tu fecha a un moment, pasándole tu string y formato, y puede regresarla en un Date.

```
this.consultas.forEach( (e) => {
    e.StartTime =  moment(e.StartTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').toDate();
    e.EndTime =  moment(e.EndTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').toDate();
});
```

Comment: Hacer el parse de esta manera convertiría los datos asi `{EndTime: Wed Sep 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora de Ecuador),  StartTime: Tue Sep 29 2020 08:14:39 GMT-0500 (hora de Ecuador),  Subject: "Blue Moon Eclipse", id: 1}` y en la documentación muestra que deben quedar formateados asi `   {Id: 1,Subject: 'Explosion of Betelgeuse Star',StartTime: new Date(2019, 0, 6, 9, 30),EndTime: new Date(2019, 0, 6, 11, 0)}`

Comment: pero al final el campo lo que ocupan es que sea del tipo Date(), es lo que te regresa un new Date(2019,0,6,9,30), es solo el constructor de tu fecha.

Comment: no importa como lo generes, lo que tienes que enviar es un parámetro de tipo Date

Comment: Tu respuesta es correcta, pero tenemos un incoveniente, los datos en el json para se puedan mostrar por el componente de [https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/schedule/default] deben tener exactamente este formato `Id: 1, Subject: 'Server Maintenance', StartTime: new Date(2018, 1, 11, 10, 0),  EndTime: new Date(2018, 1, 11, 11, 30), EventType: 'maintenance', City: 'Seattle',  CategoryColor: '#1aaa55'  }` con tu sugerencia no asume ese formato.

Comment: Hice algunos cambios a esto ` this.consultas.forEach( (e) => {  e.StartTime =  `new Date(${e.StartTime})`; e.EndTime =  `new Date(${e.EndTime})`;  });` pero me entrega esto `{ EndTime: "new Date(2020,9,29,18,55,06)",StartTime: "new Date(2020,9,29,17,55,06)",Subject: "atomic1", id: 1}];` Cambiando el formato en mi Backend que me devuelve esto `[ { "id": 1,  "StartTime": "2020,9,29,17,48,32", "EndTime": "2020,9,29,18,48,32", "Subject": "atomic1" }]`

Comment: te dejo el ejemplo que se genera desde el sheduller de la documentación, con las fechas como tu las obtienes, [ej2-angular-schedule](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxso9s?file=data.ts),

Comment: Ya le di solución al problema, utilicé [https://fullcalendar.io/], y cambie algunas cosas en el backend y obtuve los datos tal y como los pedía, el ejemplo. Gracias por la ayuda